# How to write a Dockerfile for a custom python project?

Tags: python, docker, mesos

I'm pretty new to Docker, and I need to create the container to run Docker container as an Apache Mesos task.

The problem is that I can't find any relevant examples. They all are centered around Web development, which is not my case.

I have a pure Python project with large number of dependencies ( like Berkeley Caffe or OpenCV ). 
How to write a Docker file to properly enroll all dependecies ( and how to find them out?)

Comment: You can read this document https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/ and follow links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docker hub registry contains a number of official language images, which you can use as your base image.

- https://hub.docker.com/_/python/

The instructions tell you how you can build your python project, including the importation of dependencies.

```
├── Dockerfile                <-- Docker build file
├── requirements.txt          <-- List of pip dependencies
└── your-daemon-or-script.py  <-- Python script to run
```

Image supports both Python 2 and 3, you specify this in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-onbuild
CMD [ "python", "./your-daemon-or-script.py" ]
```

The base image uses special [ONBUILD instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild) to all the hard work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I had understood basic part on building Docker images. So, in reality the best way to pack my Python project inside of Docker image is to make a Python .egg and upload it to PIP repository? Another ( crude ) option could be to make .tgz, upload it somewhere, and then just add RUN wget 'http://somewhere/my_package.tgz', right?

Comment: Packaging your software always makes it simpler to deploy, so uploading to python repository cannot be a bad thing. Having said that the python docker image will copy the local directory into the "/usr/src/app" within the container so that might be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The official Docker site has some [step-by-step](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockerimages/#building-an-image-from-a-dockerfile) and [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) documentation.

However, to get you started: what might help is to think about what you would do if you were to install and start your project on a fresh machine. You'd probably do something like this...

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python python-opencv wget ...
# copy your app into /myapp/
python /myapp/myscript.py
```

This maps more or less one-to-one to

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Vast Academician <vast@example.com>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python python-opencv wget ...
COPY /path/on/host/to/myapp /myapp
CMD ["python", "/myapp/myscript.py"]
```

The above is untested, of course, but you probably get the idea.