# How do I write Dockerfile for my Python application?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I can do it in a monolithic way:

**Monolithic**

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:10.0
RUN pip install --requirements requirements.txt # assume 400 MB
RUN pip install application:<tag>
```

Or use a more modular approach using an extra base:

**Modular**

base.Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:10.0
RUN pip install --requirements requirements.txt
```

main.Dockerfile

```
FROM application-base:latest
RUN pip install application:<tag>
```

This question [How to write a Dockerfile for a custom python project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381370/how-to-write-a-dockerfile-for-a-custom-python-project) seems to recommend the first approach; but I am afraid that would lead to more wasted disk space compared to the latter?

Suppose something changes in my `requirements.txt` (which will happen once in 3 months), Docker would need to create a new layer of 400 MB right? Won't the second approach understand the delta changes correctly? The only challenge I can see is:

1. How do I version my `base` image - possibly the tag where `requirements.txt` was last updated?
2. Complexities associated with maintaining multiple Dockerfiles.

I don't know if people rely on docker repositories, but I think it is going to be needed right (at-least until you phase off that version or something)?

Comment: IMO, if the change occurs in requirements.txt, then docker would need to create new layer in both the cases.

Comment: That seems true @ajaygandhi ... :) I think it only matters when there are multiple projects using the same app `base` which is rare!

Comment: The two approaches you describe are identical, and both will result in the same images with the same layers (the second will have one additional image tag).  If the `pip install` step results in 400 MB of content (you'd see the same thing in a host virtual environment) you can't really avoid having the image be that size.

Comment: Yup. I agree with @DavidMaze. Both the approach will results in same number of layers. If you want to reduce the number of image layers, you have to write down all the Run statements into a single line. But that again depends, if you really want to reuse any layer for other image or not